# Getting error while generating iOS build using ionic that is "The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock." in MAC Mojave

Tags: ios, macos, ionic-framework, ionic3

[image]

Recently I am getting this "The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock" issue.

This source codes were running good in previous mac OS, means after Mojave update it build is not running... I have checked and tried to solve by cocapods related issue.

I have checked many similar questions answers but no one is working for me.

Is there any solution at this situation?

Answer (score 0):

as the error say u need to install the pod or update cocoa pods in your project run:
to install cocoapods

`sudo gem install cocoapods
 pod repo update`

and then go to platform/ios and run :

```
pod install
```

and if need it remove the ios platform and add it again to 4.5.5 and install the pod again